# js undefined error index.html to other js

Tags: javascript, undefined

js undefined error

we have the following widget code :
index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
 var param1 = "value";
 var param2 = "value2";

  //]]>
  </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/widget.js"></script>
```

widget.js

```
 var param1;
 var param2;
 document.write('<iframe '
                        + ' allowtransparency="true"'
                        + ' src="http://example.com/html/'
                        + '?param1='  + param1
                        + '&param2='  + param2
                        + '">'
                        + '</iframe>');
```

but
widget.js L6 param1== undefined and param2== undefined
why?
 param1 is dead at widget.js L1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must remove variable definitions in widget.js, var keyword defines new variable with value of undefined.

```
var param1; //remove this
var param2; //remove this
 document.write('<iframe '
                        + ' allowtransparency="true"'
                        + ' src="http://example.com/html/'
                        + '?param1='  + param1
                        + '&param2='  + param2
                        + '">'
                        + '</iframe>');
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for my wrong code . and I can solve the problem . thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess and suggest that that isn't the complete widget.js, and that the code you have provided is inside a function call.

The first two lines of the widget.js code you have posted will create new versions of param1/2 in the local scope and they will be undefined.

Remove those lines.

Comment: I removed but the problem is not resulved

Comment: @fred post your new code after removing those lines, maybe you removed the wrong lines..